# Объяснить по коду

Tags: javascript

```
function sumOf(current, max, action) {
    let result = 0;
    for (; current<max; current++) {
        result += action(current);
    }
    return result;
}
let sum = sumOf(1,10, i => i);
```

Кто может объяснить в данном коде значение action(current) в цикле? Я понимаю, что туда подставляется функция, но как? Почему в скобках current, когда в функции i

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`i => i` тоже самое, что и `function(i) {return i}`, и ей не важно как мы назовем аргумент `i`, `j` или `k`.

те:

```
function sumOf(current, max, action) {
    let result = 0;
    for (; current<max; current++) {
        result += action(current);
    }
    return result;
}
let sum = sumOf(1,10, function(argument) {return argument});
```

Comment: да, это я понимаю, но что значит запись action(current) в цикле?

Comment: вызов анонимной функции, которую передали 3-им аргументом

Comment: т.е. вместе action(current) там будет function(current) по сути? и каждую итерацию цикла current будет увеличиваться на 1?

Comment: Да, типа того..